# Dica para otimização de código em C

Tags: c

Do jeito que eu escrevi o código abaixo fica muito extenso. Como deixar o código mais enxuto?

```
void mostrasaida(char recebido)
{
    int dadoA [5] = {252, 146, 145, 146, 252};
    int dadoB [5] = {255, 201, 201, 201, 182};
    //Varios vetores de AaZ
    int cont=0;
    switch (recebido) //Pesquisa o caractere recebido e imprime
    {
        case 'A': //Se o caractere recebido for A
        for(cont=0; cont<5; cont++)//Gostaria de não ter que fazer esse laço para cada vetor.
        {
            saida (dadoA[cont]); //Envia
        }
        break;
        //----------------------------------------------------
        case 'B': //Se o caractere recebido for A
        for(cont=0; cont<5; cont++)//Então executa o laço for por cinco veses
        {
            saida (dadoB[cont]); //Envia
        }
        break;
    }
}
```

Eu gostaria de não ter que fazer o laço para cada vetor. Pois haverá vários vetores.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Otimizar é diferente de encurtar.

Esse código parece bem artificial e pouca coisa pode ser feita. Dá para organizar mais, deixar mais limpo.

Dá para tirar os comentários que não tem função alguma nele.

Pode encurtar usando algumas regras sintáticas, mas eu não gosto muito de fazer isso.

Pode declarar variável onde já vai usar e economizar uma linha.

O que mais poderia dar algum ganho é colocar o laço em uma função que trate os 2 vetores. Na verdade nem vai encurtar, mas vai deixar sem repetição.

Se quer varrer um vetor tem que ter uma laço. Pode por em outros lugares. Eventualmente poderia mudar a função saída para trtar isso, mas ele ficaria menos genérica.

```
void varreVetor(int vetor[5]) {
    for(int cont = 0; cont < 5; cont++) saida(vetor[cont]);
}
void mostrasaida(char recebido) {
    int dadoA[5] = {252, 146, 145, 146, 252};
    int dadoB[5] = {255, 201, 201, 201, 182};
    switch (recebido) {
        case 'A':
            varreVetor(dadoA);
            break;
        case 'B':
            varreVetor(dadoB);
            break;
    }
}
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/Algorithm/NoLoop.c).

Answer (score 4):

Em vez de passares os elementos do array uma a um, passa o array (convertido para um apontador para o primeiro elemento) e o seu tamanho duma vez.

```
switch (recebido) {
    case 'A': saida_completa(dadoA, sizeof dadoA / sizeof *dadoA);
              break;
    case 'B': saida_completa(dadoB, sizeof dadoB / sizeof *dadoB);
              break;
    default:  /* erro */
              break;
}
```

Dentro da função fazes o loop.
A função seria qualquer coisa como

```
void saida_completa(int *a, int n) {
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        saida(a[i]);
    }
}
```